# Evaluate web application mockups

Tags: user-centered-design, mockup, interview

I'm currently working on the reconception of a web application. I already sent a survey to users to get some feedback on the current application.

I used this feedback to create low fidelity mockups (with Balsamiq) of a new interface to demonstrate to the organization the UI elements and transitions between the different screens (so there is no design element). I have multiple versions of some screens.

I now want to get some feedback from users with the aim of improving it, and for screens which have multiple versions, select the most coherent ones according to users' feedback.

So I'm going to lead some group interviews to present my work to users, but I'm asking myself if it's relevant to lead **group** interviews for this step ?
I guess individual interviews would have been better but I want to reach more users and try to get more feedback in less time for this step. And later, lead some individual interviews when I will have created an high fidelity prototype.

Is there someone who can enlighten me about the cases where using group interviews is relevant ? And if my situation does or doesn't part of those cases ?

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself individual user testing would be better.

Focus groups tend to be more about what the users want from the system and less about how users actually interact with the system.

Additional to that, focus groups or group interviews often have an element of "societal pressure". As in, you will find people agreeing with the general consensus of a group even if they personally do not because they wish to avoid confrontation, they don't want to stand out etc.

Especially since what you want to test is new UI screens. You should aim for individual feedback. If you are short on time and cannot perform usability tests yourself, I'd suggest looking into online usability platforms. A lot of them allow you to submit your designs/ux tests and they approach multiple users from across the globe. And due to time-zone differences, you might get your results sooner than you think.

There is a great [NN/G article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/focus-groups/) about the usefulness of focus groups and when to use them.